# How should PHP receiving end look like when using JS Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

just a quick question.

```
eventReceive: function(info) {
        //get the bits of data we want to send into a simple object
        var eventData = {
          title: info.event.title,
          start: info.event.start,
        };
        //send the data via an AJAX POST request, and log any response which comes from the server
        fetch('<?php \E::get('obj_curr_module')->build_action_path('dev_guideline_ui_calendar','add_event'); ?>', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: encodeFormData(eventData)
          })
          .then(response => console.log(response))
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
      },
```

My eventData is set as JS format. After using the function encodeFormData, i was wondering how should my php receiving end file looks like in order to retrieve the eventData pass on in the body?

My encodeFormData function is as below,

```
const encodeFormData = (data) => {
      var form_data = new FormData();

      for (var key in data) {
        form_data.append(key, data[key]);
      }
      return form_data;
    };
```

Comment: Using a POST request with a `FormData` body, the data should end up in `$_POST` on PHP’s side. You could check this by executing `var_dump($_POST);` in the PHP code and checking what is logged to your browser console

Comment: @rickdenhaan how to know what are the data that is in my `$_POST` if i am using ajax ?

Comment: Look at the method of the fetch, which has: `method: 'POST'` which _POSTS_ the data to the first parameter of the fetch. Plus, the code comment claims: `send the data via an AJAX POST request` too. The `var_dump` mentioned previously will show what that array contains, if anything, after submit. Also, keep the brower's web tools `console` tab open so you can check for any possible JS errors. The `network` tab will show the ajax calls, and you can check the response info too, unless you see 500 errors, then need to check the webserver error log for clues.

Comment: @Kinesis Your JS implementation calls `console.log()` on whatever your PHP script outputs. So the result of `var_dump($_POST)` in your PHP script should show up in your browser console. If your browser rejects the response because of the requirement for an "application/json" response, you could try `header('Content-Type: application/json'); exit(json_encode($_POST));` instead.